# Color row of Datatable using a SQL query in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I need to color rows of my asp.net c# table. 
To show the table, Im using one ASP:Repeater with html:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-MaquinasCaidas" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Hora Reportada</th>
                <th>Máquina</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterMaquinaCaida" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>

                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblHoraReportada" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HoraReportada") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNoMaquina" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoMaquina") %>' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

in .cs page, to fill the table:

```
public void fillTable()
    {
        string query = "SELECT * FROM MaquinaCaida order by HoraReportada asc";
        DataTable tableResponse = SqlComm.SqlDataTable(query);
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            repeaterMaquinaCaida.DataSource = tableResponse;
            repeaterMaquinaCaida.DataBind();
        }
```

I just need to color some rows based on condition, like:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = "something";
```

And then change the color of the row to red, for example.

Is there a way to perform this action??

Answer (score 0):

You can tap into the ItemDataBound event, check the row data source for a certain condition, and then alter the row class.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterMaquinaCaida" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemDataBound"

void ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item ||
      e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
  {
    if (((Evaluation)e.Item.DataItem).Rating == "Good") //check your logic here
    {
      ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("RatingLabel")).Text= "<b>***Good***</b>"; //change row here
    }
  }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your `Repeater`. Something like this.

```
    <ItemTemplate>

        <tr runat="server" class='<%#(string)Eval("column") == "condition ? "redAlert" : "" %>'>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblHoraReportada" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HoraReportada") %>' />
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblNoMaquina" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("NoMaquina") %>' />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>
```